# Adding other language (like VC++ ,etc) quality profiles in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

How can i set quality profile for languages like VC++ . When I am clicking on 'Create' in quality profiles it shows only java,C#,javascript in dropdown. Can I add quality profiles for languages other than these three ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profile creation dropdown is showing you a list of the languages recognized / loaded in your SonarQube instance. If you're not seeing C++, that means you don't have an analyzer on board that supports the language. Without an analyzer, there's no need for a profile because the analyzer:

- parses the language
- computes basic metrics
- provides the rules *that would go into your profile*

So your first step is to get set up with a code analyzer for the language (one is available as part of the [Developer Edition($)](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/developer/)). It will come with a default profile, and enable you to create additional profiles.